# How can I run Vue Serve without the app crashing?

Tags: vue.js

I've installed the latest version of Vue CLI (5.0.4) and I'm using Node v17.4.0

After successfully installing the CLI, I ran `vue ui` and created a Vue 3 project. When I try to run the serve command from the GUI, it builds successfully. However, I can't navigate to the project at localhost:8080 and if I go to `0.0.0.0:8080` it immediately crashes the server with the following error. I've not changed any of the code in the project, so it has the default boilerplate project.

```
$ vue-cli-service serve --open --mode development --dashboard
 INFO  Starting development server...

[3%] setup (watch run)
[9%] setup (compilation LoaderPlugin)
[24%] building (1/4 modules)
[38%] building (20/47 modules)
[51%] building (117/133 modules)
[70%] sealing (finish module graph)
[87%] sealing (record chunks)
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 1818ms17:52:52

Build finished at 17:52:53 by 0.000s

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
  - Network: http://192.168.68.121:8080/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.


node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: RSV1 must be clear
    at Receiver.getInfo (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/Coding/Vue/twotter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:189:14)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/Coding/Vue/twotter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:136:22)
    at Receiver._write (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/Coding/Vue/twotter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:83:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.socketOnData (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/Coding/Vue/twotter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1254:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
Emitted 'error' event on WebSocket instance at:
    at Receiver.receiverOnError (/Users/dillonbarnes/Documents/Coding/Vue/twotter/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1140:13)
    at Receiver.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'WS_ERR_UNEXPECTED_RSV_1',
  [Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
}

Total task duration: 5.06s
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Tried those exact versions on Chrome 100, macOS Big Sur. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I also tried reproducing. Node 17.4.0 is installed on Windows via `nvm`, and everything works fine. See if [these solutions](https://peterthaleikis.com/posts/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event.html) help. Particularly removing `node_modules` and reinstalling the dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I was using macOS Catalina with the latest version of Chrome. The issue was that Vue doesn't support Node v17 yet, so I downgraded to 16 via nvm.

Comment: @DillonB07 I am facing a similar issue, using macOS catalina, i have installed node 16.18.1 and it's currently in use but still facing the issue. Immediately the page loads, it crashes with the error, can you assist with which version exactly you downgraded to and if you required any additional settings? thanks.

Comment: I never fixed it @G3rr0n, I just gave up on Vue. I really like React and that was a horrible starting experience with Vue so I've just left it alone.

Comment: @G3rr0n - Having the same issue. Were you able to fix it?